# Spring boot failing to start application

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring boot is failing to start the application even though the build was successful. Below is error:

```
2015-02-23T17:50:00.21-0800 [DEA]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2015-02-23T17:50:00.36-0800 [App/0]   OUT 2015-02-24 01:50:00.362  INFO 31 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@432b3d10: startup date [Tue Feb 24 01:49:04 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT 2015-02-24 01:50:00.374  WARN 31 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.DestinationRegistryImpl.removeDestination(DestinationRegistryImpl.java:62)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.deactivate(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:931)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:58)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.stop(ServerImpl.java:174)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.destroy(ServerImpl.java:179)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerRegistryImpl.preShutdown(ServerRegistryImpl.java:90)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.CXFBusLifeCycleManager.preShutdown(CXFBusLifeCycleManager.java:97)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.shutdown(ExtensionManagerBus.java:318)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.shutdown(ExtensionManagerBus.java:305)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.onApplicationEvent(SpringBus.java:113)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus$1.onApplicationEvent(SpringBus.java:62)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:811)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT 2015-02-24 01:50:00.375  WARN 31 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@432b3d10: startup date [Tue Feb 24 01:49:04 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:890)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
2015-02-23T17:50:00.37-0800 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:811)
2015-02-23T17:50:02.82-0800 [DEA]     OUT Removing crash for app with id e3aea84f-1a88-48bc-b9e9-8b954132ca74
2015-02-23T17:50:02.82-0800 [DEA]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid e3aea84f-1a88-48bc-b9e9-8b954132ca74
2015-02-23T17:50:02.82-0800 [DEA]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid e3aea84f-1a88-48bc-b9e9-8b954132ca74
2015-02-23T17:50:09.56-0800 [API]     OUT App instance exited with guid e3aea84f-1a88-48bc-b9e9-8b954132ca74 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e3aea84f-1a88-48bc-b9e9-8b954132ca74", "version"=>"d5ffcec3-ee13-4ee0-b155-1e43c1062187", "instance"=>"eba899212df34aa49327abc4b8c86691", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1424742600}
```

Anyone else faced the same issue. Stuck with it for a while now.

Comment: I saw a couple of posts like this where upgrading Spring boot fixed the issue, what version of Spring boot are you using

Comment: I see a NullPointerException in Apache CXF. But the app is already dead (not accepting connections in Cloudfoundry by the looks of it). Is it a webapp? Is it accepting connections?

Comment: Apologies for replying late. This was fixed by adding the manifest.yml file in my project. This was added previously but somehow got deleted. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the manifest.yml file in the project.